# ApplicationDbContext doesn't update the field

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on this problem for a while now and I can't seem to figure out why the record doesn't update the field plannedTest.PlannedTestSession.
Does anyone have an idea why that is? In the debugger it is set if I run it trough it.

```
PlannedTest plannedTest = _context.PlannedTest.Where(x => x.TestID == test.TestID).First();

// State is valid. Create a session
ApplicationUser user = await _GetCurrentUserAsync();
PlannedTestSession plannedTestSession = new PlannedTestSession(plannedTest, TestState.PLANNED, DateTime.Parse(PlannendOnString), user);
plannedTestSession.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
_context.Add(plannedTestSession);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

plannedTestSession = _context.PlannedTestSession.First(x => x.ID == plannedTestSession.ID);

// This session is null in the database??
plannedTest.PlannedTestSession = plannedTestSession;

_context.Update(plannedTest);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: I am sorry I ment the database field but it is a property. Shall I post the PlannedTest model as well?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't update the field? The FK will have been updated when saving `plannedTestSession`. It is possible that `plannedTest` object you have in memory does not have related data loaded.

Comment: Well it gets the PlannedTest now trough the PlannedTestSession. It also got a FK in that object but it won't set the PlannedTest FK for the PlannedTestSession what I want. If they open a new session I want to update that field and it needs to find the new sessions but that's the whole problem that won't work

Comment: Please post your model classes & how you have configured relationship. And what field/property you are expecting to be updated.